# How to get next celery task_id or how to get task id from task itself (Flask) or how to set custom id for task?

Tags: python, celery

I have some celery in my flask app:

```
# Initialize Celery
celery = Celery("DockerApp", broker=config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery.conf.update(config)
```

And I have task:

```
@celery.task
def some_task(data):
    some_task.request.id #not working
    #my task code goes here
```

I need id of that task within task itself or I need to set that id my self.
Can somebody help?

When I call task:

```
result = some_task.delay(data)
print result.id #this is correct
```

That gives me correct result.

Answer (score 2):

You can also access the task's request inside the task with:

```
@celery.task(bind=True)
def some_task(self, data):
    print self.request.id
```

Comment: how to use self when no in class?

Comment: The 'bind=True' argument binds the function to Celery's Task class so that it can access attributes from the task instance.

Answer (score 1):

I got this with:

```
from celery import current_task #in task definition
print current_task.request.id
```

Thanks anyway.